# How to update settings to display image in orgmode with external viewer

Tags: org-mode, images

I am using orgmode in emacs with Ubuntu.

I would like to display images with my external viewer ( `/usr/bin/eog` ) when I specify an image with:

`[[file:Screenshot from 2022-11-03 05-03-37.png]]`

in my orgmode files.

Presently my complete file looks like this:

```
#+STARTUP: noinlineimages
** test-entry
[[file:Screenshot from 2022-11-03 05-03-37.png]]
```

and the picture gets displayed this way:
[image]

As mentioned, I would like to display that image with my external viewer ( `/usr/bin/eog` ).

As I am a real beginner with emacs, I have difficulties to know what I have to update.

This is my present emacs configuration file (the one I know about):

**~/.emacs**:

```
  ;; Added by Package.el.  This must come before configurations of
  ;; installed packages.  Don't delete this line.  If you don't want it,
  ;; just comment it out by adding a semicolon to the start of the line.
  ;; You may delete these explanatory comments.
  (package-initialize)

  (recentf-mode 1)
  (setq recentf-max-menu-items 25)
  (global-set-key "\C-x\ \C-r" 'recentf-open-files)

  (global-auto-revert-mode t)

  (setq org-startup-with-inline-images t)

  (cua-mode t)
  (setq cua-auto-tabify-rectangles nil) ;; Don't tabify after rectangle commands
  (transient-mark-mode 1) ;; No region when it is not highlighted
  (setq cua-keep-region-after-copy t) ;; Standard Windows behaviour
  (custom-set-variables
   ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
   ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
   ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
   ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
   '(custom-enabled-themes (quote (deeper-blue))))
  (custom-set-faces
   ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
   ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
   ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
   ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
   )
```

It seems to me that the directory `~/.emacs.d` does not contain any configuration. If I should show the contents of some files there: please inform me and I will update this post accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can customize `org-file-apps` for that using `M-x customize-variable`, press return, and type `org-file-apps` (the `M-x` should be reached by pressing `Alt M` on most keyboards).

Insert another element setting (upper part on the left -> press `[INS]` button):

Extension: `\.png\'`

Command: `eog %s`

I guess it is easiest to just repeat these steps for other image file extensions.

Don't forget to press `Apply and Save` before leaving the customize buffer.